# Any posible way to make secure links for multiple ips?

Tags: nginx, cdn

I'm running a fairly well used CDN system using Nginx and I need to secure my links so that they aren't shared between users.

The current config works perfectly..

```
# Setup Secure Links
secure_link      $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
secure_link_md5  "$secure_link_expires$uri$remote_addr secret";

if ($secure_link = "") { return 403; }
if ($secure_link = "0") { return 410; }
```

However with the internet going ever more mobile and with many users now coming from university campuses etc I'm seeing tons of failed requests, and annoyed end users because the requester's IP has changed between requests.

The requesting IP is almost always in the same range, so for example:

```
Original Request: 192.168.0.25
File Request:     192.168.0.67
```

I'd be happy to lock these secure links down to a range, such as

```
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255
```

or go even further and make it even bigger

```
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

but I can't figure out a way to do this in nginx, or if the secure_link feature even supports this.

If this isn't possible - does anyone have any other ideas on how to secure links that would be less restrictive, but still be reasonably safe? I had a look at using the browser string instead, but many of our users have download managers or use 3rd part desktop clients - so this isn't viable.

I'm very much trying to do this without having to have any dynamic code to check a remote database as this is very high volume and I'd rather not have that dependancy.

Comment: Why not replace `$remote_addr` with another map variable which only has? first 2/3 parts of IP ?

Comment: That looks like it might work - Have you done this before ? It looks like regex is needed to break the IP apart. If you've done it can you share the config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working thanks to @Tarun Lalwani for pointing out the maps idea.

```
# This map breaks down $remote_addr into octets 
map $remote_addr $ipv4_first_two_octets {
  "~(?<octet1>\d+)\.(?<octet2>\d+)\.(?<octet3>\d+)\.(?<octet4>\d+)" "${octet1}.${octet2}";
  default "0.0";
}


location / {
  # Setup Secure Links secure_link $arg_md5,$arg_expires;
  secure_link_md5 "$secure_link_expires$uri$ipv4_first_two_octets secret";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one auth directive within Nginx, so you could drop the IP from the secure link and specify that as a separate directive.

Nginx uses CIDR ranges, so for your example it would simply be a case of

```
allow 192.168.0.0/16;
deny all;
```

Comment: The problem is that this needs to be dynamic - I'm serving thousands of concurrent downloads all over the globe.

Comment: Oh sorry, when you said `The requesting IP is almost always in the same range` and then quoted an IP range I assumed a solution which encompassed that would be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map approach

```
map $remote_addr $auth_addr {
    default         $remote_addr;
    ~*^192\.168\.100     192.168.100;
    ~*^192\.169     192.169;
}
```

And then later use something

```
secure_link_md5  "$secure_link_expires$uri$auth_addr secret";
```

I have not used such an approach, but I am assuming it should work. If it doesn't please let me know

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now, and I've posted the working config below.